# Are "Sueino", "Olauus", and "Ericus" the subject of "invenerunt" in this sentence by Theodoricus Monachus?

Tags: syntax

This is a sentence from a medieval book known as "De antiquitate regum Norwagiensium", which was written by Theodoricus Monachus.

> Quinto ergo anno regni Olaui, filii Tryggua, intulerunt ei bellum Sueino, Olauus, Ericus, et eum nimis imparatum invenerunt.

Thoughts: Please note that "Sueino" is written in nominative case, despite not looking like a name in the nominative case. I am fairly certain that "Sueino", "Olauus", and "Ericus" are the subjects for the verb "intulerunt". I also think that the verb "invenerunt" refers back to these three subjects. What I am curious about, however, is whether these nouns are implicit subjects for the verb "invenerunt" or not.

Comment: Question for clarification. if the verb *invenerunt* referes to the names/nouns that just mentioned why would it count as implicit? Note sure I understand at what case they are implicit?

Comment: Actually, *Sueino* **does** look like a name in the nominative case, like Cicero, Naso or Varro. Now, the genetive *Tryggua* is another matter...

Answer (score 3):

My first (non-expert) thought is that Sueino, Olauus, and Ericus are the subjects of *intulērunt,* and continue as the subject of *invenērunt,* particularly because the plural verb agrees and partly because of sense:

> And so, in the fifth year of Olav, son of Tryggya's reign, Sueino, Olaf, and Eric brought him war and found him too unprepared.

I see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAlmL0TNnrMC&lpg=PA322&ots=BVmrmXtE0w&dq=%22intulerunt%20ei%20bellum%22&pg=PA322#v=onepage&q=%22intulerunt%20ei%20bellum%22&f=false) that this is the first sentence of a chapter titled *De morte Olaui filii Tryggya,* so it looks like events are not going Tryggya's way.